# Foreach on checkboxes does not return values

Tags: php, php4

I made a script before, that worked completely fine in PHP 5.2. But when recently going over to my friends server (version PHP 4.4.9), I noticed some actions didn't work the way they should. The outcome of what the checkboxes returned came out crazy...

This is the code I'm using:
For the form:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Box1" name="BoxGroup[]" />Box1
<input type="checkbox" value="Box2" name="BoxGroup[]" />Box2
<input type="checkbox" value="Box3" name="BoxGroup[]" />Box3
```

For the action script:

```
if($_POST['BoxGroup'] == true){ // If one of the checkboxes were checked...
    foreach($_POST['BoxGroup'] as $value){
    $BoxGroup .= ", ".$value; // Make the array into a string
    }
    $BoxGroup = substr($BoxGroup,2); // To skip ", " from the beginning of the $BoxGroup variable
}
```

Now, what this script does, is; when a user sends the form, it checks if one of the checkboxes were checked, and if so, it will make a string, like so: "value, value" etc.
I insert these values to my database. When I preview what's been submitted to the database on a page, I get "ray / value / value", -- so only "ray" (as in "Array") was passed for the first box it seems.

Unfortunately, I can not update the server's version of PHP, since both the system operator and I, don't have the root password to it (I know it's crazy).

So what do I do?

Comment: If your sysop doesn't know how to reset root's password, get a new sysop.

Comment: stillstanding: Sorry, I was confused with some other application's version. I meant PHP 5.2. cdhowie: I think he can't even do that, since it's a server from a web hotel.

Comment: A "web hotel"? Do I want to know?

Comment: Argh, sorry. I mixed it up, thought it was called the same in English. I mean web hosting service.

Comment: I hope you have access to update php.ini or .htaccess to disable register_globals... :)

Comment: How can I disable register_globals through htaccess? I do have access to it fortunately.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Note that there may be other configuration changes (e.g. magic quotes) for you to consider.

Comment: I know what I'd prefer to change if there was anything to else to change, and if only I had access to php.ini.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
implode(', ', array_keys($_POST['BoxGroup']))
```

Comment: I wasn't looking to adding the keys to the database, but this got me to where I wanted (array_values). So I accept this answer. Thank you! =)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend the implode function: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

So your whole operation will getting a bit shorter and easier to overview.
cheers

Answer (score 0):

The other comments regarding `implode` are good advice, but I don't see how it fixes your problem. (Well, it actually could, if you initialize the variable to the return value of `implode`, but that doesn't fix the core issue here.)

Initialize `$BoxGroup` properly. I bet `$BoxGroup = 'Array';` before the loop even runs... probably due to register_globals turned on. Eeeek, disable that.

In .htaccess:

```
php_flag register_globals off
```

To elaborate, I assume that if you did a `var_dump($BoxGroup)`, you'd see that it already contains those values thanks to register_globals. The array gets treated as a string 'Array' when you concat it with another string.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems turning register_globals off does not work.

Comment: Make sure `AllowOverride Options` is enabled for that directory.

Comment: Uh-huh. I tried "AllowOverride Options All", but the host just gave me error 500.